# Re: Computed column by subtracting two other columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following columns in my table name Trip;

```
trip_no (PK, int, not null),
ID_company (FK, int not null),
plane (char(25), not null),
town_from (char(25) not null),
town_to (char(25) not null),
time_out (datetime, not null),
time_in (datetime, not null),
time_out_only (time(0), null),
time_in_only (time(0) null),
time_in_flight (time(0) null);
```

For the last three columns My first row would look like this;

```
time_out_only   time_in_only   time_in_flight
 14:30:00        17:50:00        null
```

I want the time in flight to compute to 02:20:00. So I tried the the code to time_in_flight equal to time_in_only less time_out_only, as follows,

```
ALTER TABLE Trip
SET time_in_flight = time_in_only - time_out_only;
```

The error message I receive is

> "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2. Incorrect syntax near
>   'Time_in_Flight".

Unless I am incorrect in is using SET and I should be using a different function, I am confused as to where I am going wrong. However I thought this syntax worked for me before.

Can anyone guide me on where I am going wrong here, and help me figure out how to subtract the two columns using some function and formula.

Thanks Josie

Comment: Nosy curious: Can you have flights from 23:30 to 1:50 (aka from day to next day)? Can you have flights (trips, journeys) that last for over 24 hours?

Comment: @PhilipKelley.......yes I can have flights that last over 24 hours, see discussion at the end. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no substract operator for time. So using

```
SELECT time_in_only - time_out_only
FROM trip
```

you will get:

> Operand data type time is invalid for subtract operator.

If you want computed column you can first `DROP column` and recreate it:

```
ALTER TABLE Trip
DROP COLUMN time_in_flight;

ALTER TABLE Trip
ADD time_in_flight 
  AS  DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, time_out_only,time_in_only), CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME));
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384317)**</kbd>

If you don't want to recreate table structure, and calculate manually use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE Trip
SET time_in_flight = DATEADD(mi, 
                  DATEDIFF(mi, time_out_only,time_in_only), CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME));
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384321)**</kbd>

Last possible solution is to create view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_Trip
AS
SELECT -- cols,
   time_in_flight = DATEADD(mi,
                 DATEDIFF(mi, time_out_only,time_in_only), CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME))
FROM Trip
```

Comment: Thank you, I used used your first example, I dropped the column then re-created it and that worked but I have one question. One row has a time out of 16:20 and a time in of 03.40 which computes to a negative 760minutes. How would I format my column to reflect 24 hour clock and ensure my answer is positive?

Comment: @Josie Check https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384364 your answer is positve, you will get `11:20:00` which is correct

Comment: @Josie Anyway how do you calculate this? 16.20 to 3.40 - time span is `11:20` and `680 min` not 760. If you need minutes use: `DATEDIFF(mi, '00:00:00',DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, time_out_only,time_in_only), CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME)));`

Comment: You are correct the answer is 680 minutes. I dropped the column and had an error in my syntax when I re-created it. Thanks

Comment: when I used the first code, (correctly) the result came out in hours and when I used the last code, the result came out in minutes. I was looking for the result in minutes, but it was certainly helpful to learn both ways. Thanks a million.