# Sum is not summing for me in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following tables in sql. I only put in a small amount of table data here for ease of reading and excluded columns that are not relevant for this question.

Table Trip (including time_out_only and time_in_only as these were used for computed column time_in_flight):

```
 trip_no (PK, int not null)
 time_out_only (time(0) null)
 time_in_only (time(0) null)
 time_in_flight (computed, time(3) null)
```

Table Passengers_in_trip:

```
  trip_no (PK, FK, int not null)
  id_psg (PK, FK, int not null)
```

Table Passengers:

```
  id_psg (PK, int not null)
  name (char(20) not null)
```

The information on two of the passengers is as follows;

Table - Trip (only including trip no and time_in_flight)

```
 Trip No     time_in_flight
  1100             200
  1181             109
  1187             117
  1188             118
```

Table - Passengers_in_trip:

```
  Trip No         IS_Psg
   1100             1
   1181             1
   1187             8
   1188             8
```

Table - Passengers:

```
  ID_Psg           Name
   1               Joseph Smith
   8               Elaine McCoy
```

Question / Query:
Find the passengers who have spent the most time flying.

I have tried the following syntax

```
 SELECT SUM(Trip.time_in_flight) AS total_flying_time, Passenger.name
 FROM Trip
 JOIN Pass_in_trip
 ON Trip.time_no = Pass_in_trip.trip_no
 JOIN Passenger
 ON Pass_in_trip.ID_Psg = Passenger.ID_Psg
 GROUP BY Trip.time_in_flight, Passenger.name;
```

The results should be 309 for Joseph Smith (ID_Psg 1) and 235 for Elaine McCoy (ID_Psg 8)

However my syntax does not sum up for me. My results show up as follows;

```
Name                total_flying_time
Joseph Smith           200
Joseph Smith           109
Elaine McCoy           117
Elaine McCoy           118
```

I have tried variations of the above syntax, but nothing is summing the passengers, to give me a total flying time by passengers, so I can order them by highest flying time, or even select the top 5.

I am not sure if because the time_in_flight is a computed column that it impacts on the sum. But surely SQL allows us to sum computed columns.

I think my joins are correct to acquire a result of passenger name. So I am not sure where I am going wrong on this query.

Can anyone help? I have searched for answers and tried different syntax but nothing is working and its getting frustrating.

All help gratefully received.

Thanks Josie

Comment: Well, you are grouping by `time_in_flight`, that doesn't make sense really. Remove it from the `GROUP BY` and it will give you the results you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not group by `Trip.time_in_flight`:

```
SELECT SUM(Trip.time_in_flight) AS total_flying_time, Passenger.name
FROM Trip
JOIN Pass_in_trip
 ON Trip.time_no = Pass_in_trip.trip_no
JOIN Passenger
  ON Pass_in_trip.ID_Psg = Passenger.ID_Psg
GROUP BY Passenger.name;
```

Comment: @Josie You're welcome. Funny thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503731/re-computed-column-by-subtracting-two-other-columns-in-sql-server :)